# How to randomly split grouped dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
               "player_id":[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6],
               "year"     :[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
               "overall"  :[20,16,7,3,8,80,20,12,9,3,2,1]})
```

what is the easiest way to randomly sort it grouped by player_id, e.g.

| player_id | year | overall |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 80 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 16 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And then split it 80-20 into a train and testing set where they don't share any player_id.

Comment: You can/should randomly select 80-20 `player_id` and then select the data on those `player_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quang Hoang suggested in the comments. You can split your ids and then select the data based on those ids.

```py
test_ids = df.player_id.drop_duplicates().sample(frac=0.2).values
#-> array([2])

train_data = df[~df["player_id"].isin(test_ids)]
"""
    player_id  year  overall
0           1     1       20
1           1     2       16
4           3     1        8
5           3     2       80
6           4     1       20
7           4     2       12
8           5     1        9
9           5     2        3
10          6     1        2
11          6     2        1
"""

test_data = df[df["player_id"].isin(test_ids)]
"""
   player_id  year  overall
2          2     1        7
3          2     2        3
"""
```

Comment: But doing it this way you don't really randomize the player_id list, which is something I want to avoid

Comment: @Diego you mean randomize data in the train data after the split ?

Comment: sorry, I misread your code. That was what I was looking for. Thanks